# how to assign char to const char*

Tags: c++, arrays, char

How can I assign a char to a const char* in C?

```
const char* cp;
unsigned maxlen = 20;
cp = new char[maxlen];
char p = 'U';
cp = p;
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*
```

How can I assign the char p to the first element of the array cp?

Comment: This has a whiff of C++ about it - i.e. `new`. Why is it tagged C? Have you read about `const`

Comment: You just described what you need to do: _assign the char `p` to the first element of the array_. Well, you should just learn about arrays.

Comment: `cp` is not an array, and you cannot assign to its elements because it is declared `const`. I mean, that's the whole point of `const`.

Comment: Your code is highly artificial and has no comments. It is not clear what you are actually trying to accomplish. Do you want to make `cp` point to `p`? Do you want to copy `p`'s value into the array `cp` currently points to? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I assign the char p to the first element of the array cp?

You can't, because `cp` is a pointer to a `const char`. `const` prevents any mutation after initialization.

If you really want to change `cp`'s elements, remove the `const`:

```
char* cp;
unsigned maxlen = 20;
cp = new char[maxlen];
char p = 'U';
cp[0] = p;
```

Note that the above is terrible C++. You should use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays (or `std::array` for fixed-size arrays). Example:

```
std::vector<char> cp;
cp.resize(20);
cp[0] = 'U';
```

Comment: This answer is correct because it uses `std::` constructs and avoids direct use of pointers and `new`. If you want to be an RAII fanatic and be ultra-modern use `auto` and init with the desired length immediately rather than resizing later: `auto cp = std::vector<char> { 20 };`

Comment: @erapert Well, I'm pretty sure he already knows a couple of thing about `auto` ;) which was introduced in C++11, so considering it "ultra-modern" is kind of... depressing. To be nitpicking, if you want to initialize the vector with the desired size, you shouldn't use the uniform initializer `{20}` but `(20)` otherwise you create a vector with one single element of value 20 (constructor n°8 instead of n°3 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do so in a safe manner, a better idea would be:

```
char * nonConstPtr = new char[len];
*nonConstPtr = 'a';
nonConstPtr[1] = 0;
char const * constPtr = nonConstPtr;
```

You *could* do it with a cast for the code you have now, but tossing away const-ness is generally a Bad Idea (tm):

```
const char* cp;
unsigned maxlen = 20;

cp = new char[maxlen];
char p = 'U';
char * ptr = (char*)cp;
memset(ptr, 0, maxlen);
*ptr = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this acceptable or also wrong?

```
unsigned maxlen = 20;
char *cp;
cp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * maxlen);
char c = 'P';
*cp = c;
```

I understand that the null-termination is missing. I tried using strncpy but it doesn't work with char.

Thanks very much for the advise.

Answer (score -3):

How to assign a char to const char*

```
  const char* cp;
  char p = 'U';
  cp = &p;
```

Comment: This will compile your code, I'm not judging your code snippet.

Comment: `cp = new char[maxlen]; cp = ...` is a memory leak. You've just lost the only pointer to the chunk that `new` returned.

Comment: If you just want to make it compile, deleting all those lines would also do the job.

Comment: The question was regarding some specific error. And the line that had the error was the assignment of a char to a char pointer.

Comment: The question was "*How can I assign the char p to the first element of the array cp?*" Your answer does not assign `p` to the first element of the array; it throws the array away and repoints `cp` to `p`. This is not a real answer.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the question. Sorry for my bad comments, you were right.